# HBASE - org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to create `HBase` table using `Java API` and I am also facing the same error. I have set "`hbase.zookeeper.quorum`" property as well (along with few more) but I am still facing the `MasterNotRunningException` .

I am trying this out on HDP 2.5 Following is my code snippet

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.23.101:2181");
conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure");
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "sandbox.hortonworks.com");

HBaseAdmin admin = new`enter code here` HBaseAdmin(conf);
HTableDescriptor tableDescriptor = new HTableDescriptor("Test");
tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("id"));
tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("name"));
admin.createTable(tableDescriptor);
```

Following is the complete stack trace:

```
RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1511500393379, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.getInputStream(Ljava/net/Socket;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/net/SocketInputWrapper;

        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:4403)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.createTableAsyncV2(HBaseAdmin.java:748)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.createTable(HBaseAdmin.java:669)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.createTable(HBaseAdmin.java:602)
        at com.tatvasoft.hbase.CreateHBaseTable.main(CreateHBaseTable.java:44)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.getInputStream(Ljava/net/Socket;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/net/SocketInputWrapper;
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1544)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1564)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveMasterService(ConnectionManager.java:1715)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MasterCallable.prepare(MasterCallable.java:38)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:124)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.getInputStream(Ljava/net/Socket;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/net/SocketInputWrapper;
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:223)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:287)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$BlockingStub.isMasterRunning(MasterProtos.java:62739)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.isMasterRunning(ConnectionManager.java:1575)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStubNoRetries(ConnectionManager.java:1513)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1535)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.getInputStream(Ljava/net/Socket;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/net/SocketInputWrapper;
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:775)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.writeRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:887)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.tracedWriteRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:856)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1199)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:213)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.getInputStream(Ljava/net/Socket;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/net/SocketInputWrapper;
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:717)
        ... 23 more
```

Plz help resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the issue later on. It was a jar versioning mismatch error. Posting here the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkz0L.png) of the jar files I am using now with HDP 2.6

hope it helps :)